# Find all eigenvalues and vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have found the eigenvalues of the given matrix A:

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -1 & 2 \\
        -1 & 1 & 2 \\
        2 & 2 & 2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

to be -2,2,4. When looking for the eigenvectors I started by assesing the matrix when lambda is = -2 and got the matrix

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
does this mean that the eigenvector is (0,0,0) or is that impossible.

Comment: Eigenvectors are defined to be non zero. Because obviously the the zero vector satisfyes $\lambda v = A v$ for every matrix $A$ and $\lambda=0$

Comment: But to be honest, I don't understand your question and what you did to get the identity matrix. You should probably edit your question to make it more clear

Comment: I am asking how can you get a zero value, in every other example I have done the matrix reduces to a nonzero vector when putting it in rref.

Comment: It is still not clear what you did in your calculation. What does "putting in rref" mean, what does "assessing the matrix when lambda=-2" mean and what does "reducing as much as possible mean?
Please edit your question and show your calculation in detail and in a clear language. Otherwise we can only guess what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

Every non-zero vector is an eigenvector of the identity matrix.

---

**Edit**: Looking at your calculations a little further, I'm not sure how you obtained the identity matrix. To find the eigenvector for $\lambda = -2$, you should compute $(A - (-2)I)v = 0$, where $v$ is the desired eigenvector. The off-diagonal elements of $A$ should not change.

Comment: So what does this mean when compared with the case in which you get say a vector (1,0,0). Should the problem be reworked to have a vector that is non zero ?

Comment: @DougRay I've added to my answer.

Comment: In my Text Book it uses λI - A = 0. Which is what leads me to the matrix  $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} -3 & 1 & -2  \\ 1 & -3 & -2 \\ -2 & -2 & -4 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ which is how I end up with I after reducing as much as possible.

Comment: @DougRay Finding the reduced row echelon form of the above matrix (by applying rref in Matlab) yields $\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 &  0 & 1  \\
 0 &  1 & 1  \\
 0 &  0 & 0  
\end{array}
\right]$.

Answer (score 0):

If you take your matrix, assuming you computed eigenvalues correctly, then $\lambda = -2,2,4$ yields the matrices determined by $A-\lambda I$.

So, for $\lambda=-2$, it should look like:

$\begin{matrix}
        3 & -1 & 2 \\
        -1 & 3 & 2 \\
        2 & 2 & 4 \\
        \end{matrix}$